# Compare and change the content of a string in Arduino nodemcu

Tags: arduino, arduino-esp8266

I have a string but i don't seem to be able to change its content.
I want to check if the string contains "relay1" and if it does it should change its content to "15".

```
if (inputMessage1 == "relay1") {
    inputMessage1.replace("relay1", "15");
}
```

I have also tried with 'inputMessage.compareto()' but nothing.
So this is suppose to be really simple but i am going around and around.

Comment: add `inputMessage1.trim();` above the `if`

Answer (score 0):

You can check if both equals like:

```
if (inputMessage1.equals("relay1")) {
    inputMessage1.replace("relay1", "15");
}
```

if do you want to check if contains text or not then you can use like:

```
if (inputMessage1.indexOf("relay1") > 0) {
    inputMessage1.replace("relay1", "15");
}
```